# How to determine if an process is the currently active / foreground application

Tags: windows, process

I'd like to be able to query some function and give it a processID or processName - It then should return `true` or `false` on wether that process is in the foreground or not.

So i.e. the query for Firefox would return `true` (because right now I'm in FireFox, typing this) and everything else should return `false`.

Is that even possible for every type of application (.net, java/swing, pure c++/win32-ui)?

- This question is for Windows only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx) and [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) should let you get this information.

i.e., if you know the pid just check it against a function like this:

```
bool IsForegroundProcess(DWORD pid)
{
   HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
   if (hwnd == NULL) return false;

   DWORD foregroundPid;
   if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &foregroundPid) == 0) return false;

   return (foregroundPid == pid);
}
```

This will work for any application that uses the core Win32 library at some level - this'll include Windows Forms, WPF, native Win32 applications, etc.  Note this'll only work for applications running on the calling desktop and session - you can't use this to determine if another user's application is in the foreground, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if this works for DirectX / OpenGL applications?

Comment: I think it might . . . D3D apps have a focus window or device window that might work with this here.

Comment: Okay, just tried it out, seems to work well even on DirectX apps.

Comment: `if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid)` should read `if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &foregroundPid)`.  As it is, you're comparing an uninitialized DWORD value to the PID of the foreground window.