# How do I check if a certain process has focus?

Tags: vb.net, process, active-window

I'm trying to check if javaw.exe has focus, then execute certain code if it does.

Previously I had code which would look for the process ID of javaw.exe, then compare it to the process which currently had focus, which worked for awhile, but then I noticed when I had more than one javaw.exe process running, it would only work on one of those processes, while I need it to work when any javaw.exe process has focus.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()`

Comment: Whoops.  You are correct.  You'll need the `GetForgroundWindow` Win32 API function (which returns a window handle), then loop over the currently running processes, checking each for the javaw.exe process name and compare it's Main Window Handle to the foreground window handle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884256/how-to-determine-if-an-process-is-the-currently-active-foreground-application

Comment: @SamAxe : No need to loop. You can use the [**`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) function to get the id of the process owning the window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if an process is the currently active / foreground application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884256/how-to-determine-if-an-process-is-the-currently-active-foreground-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine this quite easily using the [**`GetForegroundWindow()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI functions.

First call `GetForegroundWindow` to get the window handle of the currently focused window, then call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` in order to retrieve the process id of that window. Finally get it as a [**`Process` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) instance by calling [**`Process.GetProcessById()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76fkb36k(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Public NotInheritable Class ProcessHelper
    Private Sub New() 'Make no instances of this class.
    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As UInteger) As Integer
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetActiveProcess() As Process
        Dim FocusedWindow As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
        If FocusedWindow = IntPtr.Zero Then Return Nothing

        Dim FocusedWindowProcessId As UInteger = 0
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(FocusedWindow, FocusedWindowProcessId)

        If FocusedWindowProcessId = 0 Then Return Nothing
        Return Process.GetProcessById(CType(FocusedWindowProcessId, Integer))
    End Function
End Class
```

**Usage example:**

```
Dim ActiveProcess As Process = ProcessHelper.GetActiveProcess()

If ActiveProcess IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
    String.Equals(ActiveProcess.ProcessName, "javaw", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    MessageBox.Show("A 'javaw.exe' process has focus!")
End If
```

Hope this helps!